# Call parent Object function

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

The Creator class generates his Childs. What is the best way to call ClickedOnMyChild of Creator, if Child is clicked?

```
function Creator()
{
    var c1 = new Child("Albert");
    var c2 = new Child("Sarah");

    var ClickedOnMyChild = function()
    {
       //alert name of child 
    }
}

function Child(name)
{
   this.name = name;

   function ClickHandler()
   {
      // a click on me, better call my Creator
   }
}
```

My thoughts so far:

1. static Creator (no, i need instances)
2. Trigger Custom Event in Child (my    favorite so far)
3. Pass parent instance to child (not a good practice)

Comment: There is no "best" way, it depends on your requirements. The simplest would be just `c1.click = function() { ... }` and then you just call `click` on the child whenever you need to.

Comment: What's so bad about option 3? (Especially when you know the children need to be able to tell the parent something.)

Comment: If you want `c1` and `c2` to stick to the `Creator` object, they must be defined as `this.c1 ...` and `this.c2 ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for the second: Trigger Custom Event in Child. As it not only allows you to handle the event in your parent, but also `any objects` interested in the event.

Below is a sample code:

```
    function Event(sender) {
        this._sender = sender;
        this._listeners = [];
    }

    Event.prototype = {
        attach: function (listener) {
            this._listeners.push(listener);
        },
        notify: function (args) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this._listeners.length; i++) {
                this._listeners[i](this._sender, args);
            }
        }
    };

function Creator()
{
    var c1 = new Child("Albert");
    var c2 = new Child("Sarah");

    c1.click.attach(function (sender,args){
         //alert name of child
         alert(args);
    });

    c2.click.attach(function (sender,args){
         //alert name of child
         alert(args);
    });
}

function Child(name)
{
   this.name = name;
   this.click = new Event(this);

   var _this = this;
   function ClickHandler()
   {
      _this.click.notify(_this.name);
   }
}
```

Reference link: http://alexatnet.com/articles/model-view-controller-mvc-javascript

Comment: Really nice. With example code. Im gonna use it for foreign classes.

Answer (score 2):

Option number 3. `is indeed a good practice`. If you would have ever programmed something, where you need to keep hierarchy, you would understand how awesome it could be. You could change your child class to this and explicitly set creator in `Creator` class by calling `setCreator` method:

```
function Child(name)
{
   this.name = name;
   this.creator = null ;

   this.setCreator = function(creator){
     this.creator = creator ;
   }

   this.clickHandler = function()
   {
      if (this.creator)
        this.creator.clickedOnMyChild();
   }
}
```

Notes:

- Function names should start with a small letter
- Public properties and methods must be assigned to `this` keyword. Otherwise you will not be able to use them outside the class.

Comment: Maybe they weren't supposed to be public?

Comment: May be they are not, but I really think that event handlers are supposed to be public methods.

Comment: I always thought passing parents were bad practice. I have to look after it.

Comment: What if Creator have many Grand and Parent Classes. And the SuperGrandParent need to know if Child is clicked on?

Comment: @bergman: That should be solved using the [composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)